# can my mini ipad be found if it is reset?

Tags: ipad

My mini ipad was stolen, and I was wondering if they guessed my password and then reset my iPad would I still be able to get it back? 
Cause I know you can track it, lock it, erase iT, etc. But if they reset it, will it still work? How do I get it back then?